# How do I target a specific line dynamically from JSON with Ajax

Tags: php, json, ajax, function

I have this function that calls JSON from a php file

```
function ajax_json_data(){
    var div = document.getElementById("div");
    var hr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    hr.open("POST", "test.php", true);
    hr.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    hr.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if(hr.readyState == 4 && hr.status == 200) {            
            var d = JSON.parse(hr.responseText);            
                div.innerHTML += '<img src="images/'+d.num1.imageName+'" alt="'+d.num1.imageName+'" />';                    
        }
    }
    hr.send(null);
}
```

This is what the php file outputs

```
{

  "num1":{ "imageName":"img1.jpg","imgTitle":"Title1", "description":"desc1" },
  "num2":{ "imageName":"img2.jpg","imgTitle":"Title2", "description":"desc2" },
  "num3":{ "imageName":"img3.jpg","imgTitle":"Title3", "description":"desc3" }

}
```

My noob question is how do I target `num2` from an anchor tag like;

```
<a href="#" onClick="ajax_json_data('num2')">Next Image</a>
```

I have tried

```
function ajax_json_data(x){

        //XMLHttpRequest

  var d = JSON.parse(hr.responseText);          
    div.innerHTML += '<img src="images/'+d.+x+.imageName+'" alt="'+d.+x+.imageName+'" />';                  

    hr.send(null);
}
```

but these give me errors can anyone help?

This was my solution

```
div.innerHTML += '<img src="images/'+d.[x].imageName+'" alt="'+d.[x].imageName+'" />';
```

code and learn

Comment: Try this, `div.innerHTML += '<img src="images/'+d.x.imageName+'" alt="'+d.x.imageName+'" />';`

Comment: @rcadhikari I have tried that I get errors also

Comment: That should be work, please check the image path statically like this first. <img src="images/img1.jpg" alt="desc1" />. Otherwise there may be issue on your API calling script.

Comment: @rcadhikari that gives me this error `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0
    at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
    at XMLHttpRequest.hr.onreadystatechange (test:19)`

Comment: just in case, if its already return as json object, then you should be just using `var d = hr.responseText; `

Comment: @rcadhikari I have tried that too here is the error `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'imageName' of undefined
    at XMLHttpRequest.hr.onreadystatechange (test:20)`

Comment: I have prepared the example here, please check it https://www.w3schools.com/code/tryit.asp?filename=FDYRYLJN9K7Q